# LibGDX NullPointerException when switching screens

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, libgdx, screens

I am developing a game for Android using LibGDX. I have created several screens and I am able to visit them successfully if I have not already visited them it seems. For example, I can go from `StartScreen` to `HomeScreen` to `LoginScreen` to `MainMenuScreen` just fine. However, when I attempt to switch from my `MainMenuScreen` to the `StartScreen` of my application by clicking the logout button, I get a NPE:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mathsvszombies2.game.Screens.MainMenuScreen$3.clicked(MainMenuScreen.java:145)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener.touchUp(ClickListener.java:89)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:58)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchUp(Stage.java:353)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.processEvents(LwjglInput.java:332)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:217)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

I get the same error when I attempt to go from my `SignUpScreen` to `LoginScreen` after clicking the Sign Up `button`, however, I don't believe it is an error to do with the `button` because as I mentioned earlier, going to various `screens` initially works fine using `button` clicks (such as `HomeScreen` to `LoginScreen` using `Login` `button`). Thus, I believe there is a common `error` in my application. Let's focus on my `MainMenuScreen` to `StartScreen` error upon `logout button` click.

I start with declaring my `Game` variable at the top of the `MainMenuScreen` class:

```
private Game game;
```

This is my MainMenuScreen constructor:

```
public MainMenuScreen(Game game) {

    app.log("Screen", "Main Menu Screen");
    camera= new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(MathsVsZombies.V_WIDTH, MathsVsZombies.V_HEIGHT, camera);
    stage = new Stage(viewport);
}
```

This is where I attempt to switch screens:

```
logoutBtn.addListener(new ClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            LoginScreen.isLoggedIn = false;
            game.setScreen(new StartScreen(game));
        }
    });
```

Here is my StartScreen class - I start with declaring my Game variable at the top of my StartScreen class:

```
private Game game;
```

This is my StartScreen constructor:

```
public StartScreen(Game game){
    Gdx.app.log("Screen", "Start Screen");
    this.game = game;
    camera= new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(MathsVsZombies.V_WIDTH, MathsVsZombies.V_HEIGHT, camera);
    stage = new Stage(viewport);
    StartScreenActor actor = new StartScreenActor();
    stage.addActor(actor);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, all you have to do is add this line of code in your constructor method for any screen class you have:

```
this.game = game;
```

This is saying that this object is an instance of game. Without it, passing "game" into StartScreen when you say `game.setScreen(new StartScreen(game));` has nothing to reference to, and therefore gives a NullPointerException.

updated MainMenuScreen constructor:

```
public MainMenuScreen(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
    app.log("Screen", "Main Menu Screen");
    camera= new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(MathsVsZombies.V_WIDTH, MathsVsZombies.V_HEIGHT, camera);
    stage = new Stage(viewport);
}
```

This is the only change you have to make, and changing screens will work just fine now.